# Which C/C++/Objective C compiler should i choose in  xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, ios5

Trying to archive my app to submit to app store. 
The app can run nicely on Simulator/Device but while archiving I got the below error for cocos2d libraries.

> Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7'

In Build settings, Compiler for C/C++/Objective C are 
- Default Compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 3.0)
- Apple LLVM compiler 3.0
- LLVM GCC 4.2

Which compiler will be the better choice ?

Appreciate for any help. 
Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 is the default beginning with Xcode 4.2. I would generally advise to use LLVM 3.0 not just because it's the default but also because it reports warnings and errors for potentially dangerous code that will pass by LLVM GCC.

For example, LLVM 3.0 can check in many situations if an array access is out of bounds. It is also reporting warnings for potential "undeclared selector sent to instance" at compile time, rather than at runtime.

Another point is that LLVM 3.0 is now the default for both platforms (iOS and Mac). So if you want to develop for both platforms and want to avoid unwanted surprises, you should definitely use LLVM 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Generally use the default unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.  LLVM GCC 4.2 is the older and possibly more stable version, but LLVM has been an option long enough it should work well.

If you start seeing any odd errors, then switch back and see if it helps.